# I can't remove a directory tree with rm -rf

Tags: permissions, rm

This seems very strange to me. I'm running kernel 2.6.37.2 and ran:

```
~]$ cp -r /proc/ here
~]$ rm -rf here
```

I get some permission denies when copying as expected and I eventually hit Control-C. I get `Permission denied` on a lot of files when trying to remove the new directory and files.

As a note, I found this weird behavior because a friend sent me a `.tgz` of a snapshot of his `/proc` dir. I extracted the directory and when I was finished looking through it I had the same problem.

`rm -rf` as root does work.

`lsattr` shows the e attribute (which is what all of my files/directories show).

Comment: I've generalized the title of your question a little because the core issue isn't about `/proc`. By the way, it's a bit late for this time, but if you figure out the answer after posting the question, [it's fine to answer it yourself](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#ask), and leave it up for other people who might run into a similar problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If there is a non-empty directory where you don't have write permission, you can't remove its contents.

```
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/bar
$ chmod a-w foo
$ rm -rf foo
rm: cannot remove `foo/bar': Permission denied
```

The reason is that `rm` is bound by permissions like any other command, and permission to remove `bar` requires write permission on `foo`. This doesn't apply when you run `rm` as root because root always has the permission to remove a file.

To make the directory tree deletable, make all the directories in it writable (the permissions of regular files don't matter when it comes to deletion with `rm -f`). You can use either of these commands:

```
chmod -R u+w here        # slow if you have a lot of regular files
find here -type d -exec chmod u+w {} +
```

Comment: Still the same result "Operation not permitted"